# Automatically play video on Mac

Tags: python, css, django, macos, html5-video

I've the following code in my webpage (Python/Django framework) to enable a video to play in the background.

**HTML**

```
<div class="video-container">
    <div class="video-container-bg">
        <video playsinline autoplay muted loop poster="{{page.image.url}}" id="bgvid">
                <source src="{{page.video.url}}" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="{{page.mac_video.url}}" type="video/webm">
        </video>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8">
                    <div class="animation-element bounce-up">
                        <h1 class="page-title">{{page.page_title}}</h1>
                        <p class="strapeline">{{page.strapline}}</p>
                        <a class="butt" href="#about-us">Learn More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
video#bgvid { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height:100%;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    z-index: -100;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    background: url() no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;

}

.video-container {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 75px);
     overflow: hidden !important;
     position: relative;
}
.video-container-bg {
    padding-top: 25vh;
    color: #fff;
}
```

It works fine on everything except Safari where nothing plays.  Why not? Is it something Apple have set to prevent?  In fact, when I run Safari on Windows it's telling me it cannot play HTML5 video.  Is that right?

Comment: By "except a Mac" you mean it doesn't work in Safari? Or any browser on Mac?

Comment: I mean Safari - I haven't tested others yet

Comment: I've got no idea what is going on here.  I'm now finding people can play the videos on a modren Mac but they get no sound while for the same videos on an iPad they will not play.  It must be something to do with the codecs but I've no idea where to start

Comment: Well you muted the sound for the videos with the `muted` attribute in the `<video>` tag. iPads & iPhones with iOS 9 or earlier just don't support autoplay. More here: https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by saving the mp4 files in a lossless state.  It now seems to work.  I have no idea why